# Multiple string replacements within find command in ash

Tags: string, replace, find

I have a shell script that allows me to build a list of all my music. Running 3.2.40 GNU/Linux in a Synology NAS.

Here is what I have come up with (which works fine):

> #!/bin/ash
>      OutputPath=/volume1/MYFILES/Scans/
>      AudioFileList='ListMusic.txt'
>      AudioPath=/volume1/music/
>      SkipAlwaysPath='( -path '*/#recycle*' -path '*/.*' -path '*@*' )'
>      SkipAlwaysFiles='( -iname 'thumbs.db*' -o -iname '*.htm' -o -iname '*.html' -o -iname '*.nfo' )'
>
> find $AudioPath -type f ! $SkipAlwaysPath ! $SkipAlwaysFiles -iname '*.txt' > $OutputPath$AudioFileList

The result looks something like this:

/volume1/music/ABBA/Abba Song 1.mp3
/volume1/music/ABBA/Abba Song 2.mp3
...

I would like to REMOVE the string /volume1/music/ from the beginning of each line. I've tried a perl script that worked :

> /usr/bin/perl -pi -e 's//volume1/music///g' $OutputPath-$AudioFileList.txt

but when I try to replace the hard-coded path with $AudioPath :

> /usr/bin/perl -pi -e 's/$AudioPath//g' $OutputPath-$AudioFileList.txt

it fails (I don't know how to escape the forward slashes contained in the variable). Furthermore, I want to make the string replacement "in line" instead of scanning through the file AFTER. I tried to use the cut command, or sed, but didn't manage to get very far.

Furthermore, I want to convert the file from Unix to DOS. I have tried adding

> /usr/bin/perl -pi -e 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\r\n/g' $OutputPath$AudioFileList

After the find line, and it works, but I would again prefer to do the replacement "in-line."

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: To escape '/' do this `/usr/bin/perl -pi -e 's/\/volume1\/music\///g' $OutputPath-$AudioFileList.txt`

Comment: Actually, I had tried that and it worked (I will edit my post). The problem arises when I use the VARIABLE and not the hardcoded path.

Comment: ok, what is shown above isn't right. It mangles what I wrote, because in my post I did escape the forward slash, but that doens't fix the problems: -use a variable instead; -do the replacement inline -also convert the file to windows inline.