# How to sort the result of a find

Tags: sorting, find

I have a shell script that allows me to build a list of all my music. Running 3.2.40 GNU/Linux in a Synology NAS.

Here is what I have come up with (that works fine):

> #!/bin/ash
>
> OutputPath=/volume1/MYFILES/Scans/
>
> AudioFileList='ListMusic.txt'
>
> AudioPath=/volume1/music/
>
> SkipAlwaysPath='( -path '*/#recycle*' -path '*/.*' -path '*@*' )'
>
> SkipAlwaysFiles='( -iname 'thumbs.db*' -o -iname '*.htm' -o -iname '*.html' -o -iname '*.nfo' )'
>
> find $AudioPath -type f ! $SkipAlwaysPath ! $SkipAlwaysFiles -iname '*.txt' > $OutputPath$AudioFileList

I would like to have the whole file sorted out alphabetically, by path and filename. There are over 34000 entries in my file so performance may be an issue. If this is going to take over an hour, I could consider only sort by folders, leaving files within each folder unsorted.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Please don't cross post!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple string replacements within find command in ash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153196/multiple-string-replacements-within-find-command-in-ash)

Comment: Actually, not at all a duplicate. I originally posted a long test with 7 questions/modifications. I was told to only ask ONE question per post, so I broke down my original post (that I deleted) with a simple question per post. The premise is the same, but the questions are all different.